# Convergence of Riemann Zeta function for curves over the field $\mathbb{F_{q}}$

Tags: schemes, riemann-zeta, arithmetic-geometry, zeta-functions

Let $X$ a curve over the field $\mathbb{F_{q}}$ (proper, integral normal scheme of dimension 1). The Riemann Zeta function for this curve is defined as

$$\zeta(X,t)=\prod_{x\ \text{closed}}\ \left(1-t^{\deg(x)}\right)^{-1}$$

where $\deg(x)=[k(x):k]$, $k(x)$ is the residue field and $t=q^{-s}$, $s$ complex number. I want to make this product precise. This means that I would like to show it belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$, the formal power series. I know that actually the invertible element $\left(1-t^{\deg(x)}\right)^{-1}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ equal to

$$\left(1-t^{\deg(x)}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}t^{i\deg(x)}$$
So, this is a well defined element in $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$. I also know the fact that the number of closed points $x$ such that $\deg(x)\leq N$ is finite, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$. But I cannot use it to express the Zeta function as an element in $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$.

Comment: I think you're most of the way there: both the infinite product and the infinite sum are limits of finite sums/products, each of which is "obviously" a formal power series. The limit of the formal power series will exist precisely when, for every $n$, the terms up to $t^n$ stop changing forever when new factors/summands are included; but that's guaranteed by the observation in your second-to-last sentence.

Comment: I cannot understand when you're saying "The limit of the formal power series will exist precisely when, for every n, the terms up to tn stop changing forever when new factors/summands are included". Is it a fact of formal power series theory? Maybe I miss something

Comment: Can you see why $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-t^n)^{a_n}$ converges in $\Bbb{Z}[[t]]$ for any sequence $a_n\in \Bbb{Z}$? Similarly $\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1-t^{b_j})^{-1}$ converges in $\Bbb{Z}[[t]]$ for any sequence $b_j\in \Bbb{N}, b_j\to \infty$.

Comment: Actually, does convergence mean that we need to show the finite product is a Cauchy sequence?@reuns

Comment: That is equivalent, yes; my point is that if you look at your definition of the metric on formal power series, you'll see that being a Cauchy sequence is equivalent to the way I described it.